# How to debug into "Remote Java Application" in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debug

I'm trying to debug Ofbiz via Eclipse according to [these instructions](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Running+and+Debugging+OFBiz+in+Eclipse).

I added the project folder and Eclipse indexed it.  The instructions indicate that I should be able to click "Debug" and select "Remote Java Application"

Unfortunately when I click "Debug" my options are "Local Java Applet", "Local Java Application" and "JUnit Test".

Does anyone know what to do so that "Remote Java Application" will be an option of Eclipse?  I'm running version 3.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to click "Debug Configurations" then select remote debugging, then double click it, then from there I can access it.

Comment: Yes, that's more or less what is in my answer also...

Answer (score 1):

I have several versions of Eclipse installed (including the same as yours), and in all of them, I have the option "Remote Java Application" in the "debug configurations..." menu.

I don't think you need to do something in particular to activate them. Maybe reinstalling your Eclipse would solve the problem (eventually install in another directory, for test purposes, and point to a different workspace).